# Converting string to date , datetime or Int in Mapping dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a parquet file with a **start_date** and **end_date** columns
Formatted like this

> 01-Jan-2021

I've tried every combination conversion *toDate, toString, toInterger* functions but I still get Nulls returned when viewing the data (see image).

I would like to have see the result in two ways YYYYMMDD as integer column and YYYY-MM-DD as Date columns.
eg **01012021** and **01-01-2021**

I'm sure the default format has caused this issue.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Absolutely, and forgive my late response. I'm using the syntax right now.
Expert help! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you say `*"I would like to have see the result in two ways YYYYMMDD as integer column and YYYY-MM-DD as Date columns. eg 01012021 and 01-01-2021"*` Do you want in **YYYYMMDD** or **dd-mm-yyy** cause your example is in the later format.

Anyways, please see below expression you could use:

My source:

[image]

Use derived column:

[image]

Edit expression:

**start_date_toInteger :** `toString(toDate(substring(start_date,1,11), 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'yyyymmdd')`

**start_date_toDate:** `toString(toDate(substring(start_date,1,11), 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

[image]

Final results:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, for the Date formatter, you need to first tell ADF what each part of your string represents. Use dd-MMM-yyy for your format. Then, use a string formatter to manipulate the output as such: toString(toDate('01-Jan-2021', 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

For the integer representation: toInteger(toString(toDate('01-Jan-2021', 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), 'yyyyMMdd'))